# Constraint layout's Horizontal orientation not working

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I've 3 views, Text view, a vertical divider and switch in order  with chaining as `spread inside` now I'm trying to move vertical divider from current center towards switch by setting horizontal_bias to .8, but in horizontal_bias does not get honored, How to move vertical divider towards switch in ContraintLayout, below is the layout xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivityFragment"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/divider"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/divider2"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread_inside"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/divider2"
        android:layout_width="4dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:background="?android:attr/listDivider"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/divider"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/switch1"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.8"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat
        android:id="@+id/switch1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:checked="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/divider"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/divider2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/divider"
        android:layout_width="368dp"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="?android:attr/listDivider"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it will work in your implementation, try simply removing the view chaining then set the horizontal bias on the divider.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivityFragment"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="14dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:text="TextView"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<View
    android:id="@+id/divider2"
    android:layout_width="4dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:background="?android:attr/listDivider"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/divider"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/switch1"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.75"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

<android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat
    android:id="@+id/switch1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:checked="true"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/divider"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<View
    android:id="@+id/divider"
    android:layout_width="368dp"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:background="?android:attr/listDivider"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```